# Run Time error 3156 ODBC Delete on a linked table TABLENAME failed

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I have linked my Access database to SQL and i can execute inserts/selects from VB6 code. But, if I try to `delete * from TABLENAME` i get exception in VB6

> Run Time error 3156 ODBC Delete on a linked table TABLENAME failed

Weird thing is: I can execute same query directly in access, i get no exception and rows are deleted in SQL which acts as backend.

I have tried to create a passthrough query which also works in access but if i call it in VB6 i get exception:

> ODBC Call failed

Comment: Standard sql format would not include a field list for the delete.  Some of the db providers accept it, others don't, Try `delete from tablename where ...` for the operation.

Comment: I have tried that too. Actually my passthrough query is: "Delete from dbo.artikli". This query can be run and executes correctly when called from ms access but if i try to call it from within my vb6 application i get ODBC call failed error @MarkL

Comment: You should inspect the connection error collection when this error occurs, if you haven't already done so.  That could contain more detailed error info/messages that might point you in the direction of what's going wrong.